# Reduce for loop complexity on cursor

Tags: python, list, loops, orm

Let us consider the following case :

```
query_cursor = some query execution here
data = []
 for row in query_cursor:
     data.append({'name': query_result[row]['name']})
```

Let's assumeI got some 10,000 rows after querying, which makes this loop run 10,000 times.
Can anyone help me to optimize this code, such that it doesn't take that long?

Comment: please provide a [mcve] so people can actually run your code and see what you're having issues with.

Comment: Unless you have access to a spell book, you won't get any better than complexity O(n).

Answer (score 0):

On approach is to use a `list comprehension`

**Ex:**

```
data = [{'name': query_result[row]['name']} for row in query_cursor]
```

Comment: Rakesh, appending list with a dictionary is quite fast enough.
But getting the data from a query cursor on a loop is costly operation when the iteration level in huge.